# Is there a `:browse oldfiles` for vim sessions?

Tags: sessions

It seems to me it would make more sense to have a `:browse oldfiles` for the last n sessions you opened up / saved in vim.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

There's a single `:h v:oldfiles` list saved to / restored from `:h viminfo`. And it has nothing to do with `:h session-file`.

On the other hand, "session" does not store "oldfiles"-sort of stuff. What it contains is a buffer list (possibly including unloaded buffers, see `:h 'sessionoptions'`), but this still differs from "MRU" (Most Recently Used (files)) and such.

Another thing to remember about "session", it is a VimScript file itself, so it could be tricky to extract only partial info without fully sourcing it.